# rails importmap i am not able to add jquery module maphilight

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been working on this for some time now but i am stuck.

I make use of the maphilight jquery module. This worked in my webpack version.

In app/javascript/packs/application.js i added

```
require('maphilight')
```

and i installed it with yarn.

```
yarn add maphighlight
```

As far as i know this is all i had to do.

I added to my (haml) view de following code:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
  $('.map').maphilight();
  });
```

Now i want to port this to importmap but i do not seem to get it working.

I pinned the code

```
ruby bin/importmap pin maphilight

Pinning "maphilight" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:maphilight@1.4.2/jquery.maphilight.min.js
```

So now i am stuck.

I have added in my app/javascript/application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

// by bo
import "jquery"

console.log("Hallo");
console.log($);
console.log($(".map").maphilight());
```

As expected i get in the browser console:

```
Hallo
ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).maphilight is not a function
```

when i change my app/javascript/application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

// by bo
import "jquery"
import "maphilight"  <--- added line give error

console.log("Hallo");
console.log($);
console.log($(".map").maphilight());
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at jquery.maphilight.min.js:86:7
    at jquery.maphilight.min.js:7:3
    at jquery.maphilight.min.js:6:2
```

Could anyone tell me whats wrong ?